# Replacing XML tags conditionally in multiple files

Tags: php, xml, linux

I need to search and replace in multiple  xml files. I am looking to write a script to do this job as i have many files to edit. For example,

```
<search position="after" index="0,1,3" offset="2">
   <![CDATA[
      <?php -- code to be searched -- ?>
           ]]>
</search>
<add>
   <![CDATA[ --code to add here-- ]]>
</add>
```

```
I need to change above code to following
```

```
<search index="1,2,4">
   <![CDATA[
      <?php -- code to be searched -- ?>
           ]]>
</search>
<add position="after" offset="2">
   <![CDATA[ --code to add here-- ]]>
</add>
```

I need to 
1. move position from search and add tag, position can be 'replace','after','before'.
2. index tag should also be moved to add tag, and incremented as new index starts from 1 instead of zero
3. move offset to add tag

As far as I know Searching for a particular string and replacing is easy using `str_replace` but i cannot get how to search for a string and replace or append next line and iterating it in all files ending with .xml extension. What is the best way to do it either in php or command line?

Answer (score 1):

Well, first thing to do is to write an XSLT transformation to do this. You really don't want to attempt this at the text level - there are far too many ways of getting it wrong, especially if there are too many files to check each one by hand. The XSLT 2.0 code would be as follows (assuming a wrapper element around `search` and `add` which I will call `X`)

```
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="X">
 <xsl:copy>
  <search index="{string-join(for $t in tokenize(search/@index, ',') return string(number($t)+1))}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="search/node()"/>
  </search>
  <add position="{search/@position}" offset="{search/@offset}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="add/node()"/>
  </add>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Then you need to apply this to all files in a directory. If you're using Saxon you can do this from the command line: specify `-s:input-dir -o:output-dir`.

Comment: I am sorry but i am not familiar with XSLT transformation or know how to use it. These xml files are for a modification system from where we do modification to core php files. can you tell me if applying this is a simple process and if i need to get started which would be the best starting point to do so? Thanks

Comment: If you're manipulating XML then you need to master XSLT, just like if you're doing woodwork you need to learn to use a saw and a chisel. There's a learning curve, but you will waste far more time trying to do the job with the wrong tools than it will take you to learn the correct tools for the job.